# Installing ECL on OSX

Tags: macos, common-lisp, ecl

I need to try embeddable common lisp on my OSX. Unfortunately I think a ran into problems installing and have no idea why. I installed ecl-13.5.1 and followed the instructions on http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/pr01s06.html but ran into problems during the make command. Here's some of the messages:

```
    haukurs-mbp:ecl-13.5.1 Haukur$ make
    cd build; /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
    if (echo c gmp gc libffi atomic | grep gmp); then \
      cd gmp && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install && \
      cd .. && mv include/gmp.h ecl/ && rmdir include &&  \
      mv ./libgmp.a ./libeclgmp.a; \
    fi
c gmp gc libffi atomic
gcc -fPIC -fno-common `test -f 'gen-fac_ui_.c' || echo '/Users/Haukur/ecl-13.5.1/src/gmp/'`gen-fac_ui_.c -o gen-fac_ui
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [gen-fac_ui] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libeclgmp.a] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and the make install message:

```
haukurs-mbp:ecl-13.5.1 Haukur$ make install
cd build; /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install
# Here we would use the option -s but the install program in sourceforge-solaris
# is broken.
/bin/sh /Users/Haukur/ecl-13.5.1/src/gc/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/lib/ \
      /usr/local/lib/ecl-13.5.1/ /usr/local/include/ /usr/local/include//ecl
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/lib/ecl-13.5.1/ /usr/local/include/ /usr/local/include//ecl
```

I just don't understand the errorcodes so I don't know what went wrong. Now the website says to use OS X Tiger but I have Maverick 10.9.3. Maybe this is the error and ecl won't build with this operating system. If not,can I fix it? Unfortunately my searches have come up empty so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Managed to install this. Used gcc 4.7 but you might need to download a garbage collector in order for the install to work. I got mine from here http://hboehm.info/gc/

Comment: How did you manage to install this?